# Как вывести переменную из функции python?

Tags: python, discord, асинхронность, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def option(ctx, messages:str):
    await ctx.send('Complete!')
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await ctx.send(f'{messages}')
```

Я хочу, чтобы переменная messages, которую я прописал в async def выводилась в последней строчке кода.

Comment: Что мешает вывести её в последней строчке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего создать глобальную переменную и работать с ней из функций.

Пусть это будет `g_messages`, изначально - пустой объект. В обеих функциях прописываем строку `global g_messages` для работы с глобалкой. После этого, в функции `option()`, при получении *messages* присваиваем глобальной переменной полученное значение. После чего спокойно обрабатываем его во второй функции, уже в качестве `g_messages`

**Код:**

```
g_messages = None

@bot.command()
async def option(ctx, messages:str):
    global g_messages
    g_messages = messages
    await ctx.send('Complete!')

@bot.command()
async def on_member_join(member):
    global g_messages
    await ctx.send(f'{g_messages}')
```